# how to view a predicted classification model in a form of if-then rules

Tags: matlab, classification

I have been using matlab to predict a classification model using

```
mdl = fitcecoc(XTrain,YTrain,'Learners','linear')
```

now I can use this model for prediction but I need to extract if-then rules to define the model. Is there a way to express the model as if-then rules or even visualize it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, the `fitcecoc` function is used to fit a SVM model in MATLAB, and SVM is not based on if-the rules. Thus, you cannot express your model like that. However, you can plot your model, as explaining [in this post](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/support-vector-machines-for-binary-classification.html).